# How to change the behavior of lengthmenu in Jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have to customize the jquery datatable to change the length menu options as well as behavior.
In length option , I need to specify certain text as "Initiated, "dispatched", "received" , based on these statuses, I need to filter the rows which have status column matching "Initiated, "dispatched", "received" respectively.

How do i go about it? Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: lengthMenu doesn't do that, lengthMenu is a number of items to display, not a filter. If you want to filter by column values, try looking at this example here: http://live.datatables.net/cusologu/6/edit

Comment: @colin0117, thanks a lot, this helped me getting started

Answer (score 2):

Most of the properties of Jquery datatable are applied in below code, as you do not identify the proper option to change, you can try with those.

```
$('#dtId').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/search/LoadData",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },

            "info": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "paging": true,
            "pageLength": 10,
            "ordering": true,
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ Per Page",
                "info": "Displaying _START_ - _END_ of _TOTAL_",
                "paginate": {
                    "first": '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" ></i> First',
                    "previous": '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" ></i> Previous',
                    "next": 'Next <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" ></i>',
                    "last": 'Last <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" ></i>'
                },

            },
            "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-4'i><'col-sm-4'p><'col-sm-4'l>>" + "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>",
            "scrollX": true,
            "lengthMenu": [
                 [5, 10, 15, 20, -1],
                 [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
            ],
            "buttons": [
                'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
            ] 
        });
```